# How to set title and description and 'Watch More' on a Video

Tags: facebook

How to set title and description and 'Watch More' on a Video.

Just like this-

[image]

[Video Link](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10152287140228887&set=vb.9733218886&type=2&theater)